# Do I need to upgrade ?

Tags: upgrade

For my netbook shutdown problem with Ubuntu 14.04 , I install 14.10 .
14.10 is works well even shutdown and reboot works well. but when I
upgrade 14.10 to 15.04 . It's become again shutdown problem which I face
with Ubuntu 14.04. Linux mint 17.2 works well with my netbook. but I love
to use Ubuntu. I know mint also Ubuntu base. 
now my question is do I need to upgrade 14.10 to 15.04 ? I mainly use
skype, libreoffice , VLC , and visit few website.

Comment: The problem may be due to 15.04 using different system to start services, so it is somewhat different now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is short and the answer is **Yes**. Ubuntu 14.10 is not longer supported. And if 14.04 is not working for you, then you have to take the bull by the horns. Have a break with the next LTS release, Ubuntu 16.04.